# Set the Menu button to Back button (working with Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, navigation-drawer, back-button

I'm using navigation drawer : 
I try using this code in my fragment:

`((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

How to use up/back button on action bar?

Comment: That call should have worked. What theme have you applied to your Activity?

Comment: Did you try to add `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`?

Comment: Nop ! 
i use ` <style name="MaterialDrawerBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">` Theme

Comment: Change the parent value to `Theme.AppCompat` only. With the NoActionBar theme, your ActionBar won't show. Neither your home button.

Comment: Because i'm using ToolBar the app craches ! 
i try adding `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` to the theme ! 
Maybe  adding ClickListener To DrawerNavigationUpButton on the NavigationDrawer solves the problem ! ?

Comment: I found this solution : 
`result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
**result** : the drawer constructor on ParentActivity.